# Core data empty after crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I'm simulating a crash to test out how my app responds and noticed that my `core data` is empty when relaunching the app.  Until now, using core data and `NSFetchRequest` has been working perfectly - I can terminate the app or turn off the phone and the data always remains.  I'm using core data to store the URLS to audio files stored in `NSFileManager`.  When I relaunch the app, I can see that the files are still in `NSFileManager` but `NSFetchRequest` returns a count of zero and my `tableview` is empty.  Anyone experience this before?

EDIT:  I've been simulating crashes using these two lines:

```
    NSArray *array = @[];
    array[1];
```

In `viewDidLoad` of my main view controller, I call the following:

```
self.managedDocument = [OSManagedDocument getInstance];
[self.managedDocument setUpDocument];
```

managedDocument is a singleton that contains all my methods for data management.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSManagedObjectContext * managedObjectContext;


+(OSManagedDocument*) getInstance
{
    static OSManagedDocument* _instance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _instance = [[OSManagedDocument alloc] init];
    });
    return _instance;
}

-(void) setUpDocument
{

    if(self.document == nil)
    {
        NSFileManager * fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSURL * documentsDirectory = [[fileManager URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] firstObject];
        NSString * documentName = @"MyRecordings";
        self.url = [documentsDirectory URLByAppendingPathComponent:documentName];
        self.document = [[UIManagedDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:self.url];


        BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[self.url path]];

        if(fileExists)
        {
             [self.document openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
                if(success)
                {
                    [self documentIsReady];

                }

             }];
        }
        else
        {
             [self.document saveToURL:self.url forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating completionHandler:^(BOOL success){
                if(success)
                {
                     [self documentIsReady];

                }
                else
                {
                    NSLog(@"Fail");
                }

            }];

        }
    }
}

-(void) documentIsReady
{

    if(self.document.documentState ==UIDocumentStateNormal)
    {
        self.managedObjectContext = self.document.managedObjectContext;
        NSLog(@"context is ready");
        [self fetchControllerFiles];
        [self recordingCount];
    }
}

-(int) recordingCount
{

    NSFetchRequest * request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Recording"];
    NSError *error;
    request.predicate = nil;
    request.sortDescriptors =nil;
    NSArray * recordings = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    NSLog(@"recordings count %lu", (unsigned long)recordings.count);
    return (int)[recordings count];
}
```

When my app relaunches after a crash, I call the following:

```
 -(void) appBecameActive:(NSNotification *)notification
 {
     self.managedDocument = [OSManagedDocument getInstance];
 }
```

I call this method to add to core data

```
-(void) saveRecording:(NSMutableDictionary*) recordPackage inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext*) context
{

    Recording * recording = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Recording" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    recording.trackTitle = [recordPackage objectForKey:@"track label"];
    recording.audioURL = [[recordPackage objectForKey:@"audioURL"] absoluteString];
    recording.timeAdded = [NSDate date];
    recording.waveData = [recordPackage objectForKey:@"waveData"];
    recording.minAmpl = [recordPackage objectForKey:@"minAmpl"];
    recording.recordingNumber = [recordPackage objectForKey:@"recordingNumber"];


}
```

Comment: Is `[OSManagedDocument getInstance]` returning a value?  Or `nil`?  What path through your `if else` statements is `setUpDocument` method taking?

Comment: OSManagedDocument isn't returning nil.  For the path, it recognizes `filesExist` as true, `success` as true, then calls `[self documentIsReady]`

Comment: `UIDocumentStateNormal` is true?

Comment: Yes.  Never have a problem entering that IF statement.  I've been simulating crashes by doing `NSArray *array = @[];` then calling `array[1];`

Comment: What's going on when it crashes?  Is core data empty in the moment just before the crash?  Is the crash happening during a file write and corrupting the file?

Comment: Core data already has data before crashing.  I'm forcing the crash to happen while I'm creating an audio recording.  I need to tap save in order to add the data to core data, but since I crash before hitting save, the file data never gets added to core data - which is good.  But when I relaunch, all the older core data stuff is gone.

Comment: Do your fetches return nil, or an empty array?

Comment: When I call recordingCount after a crash it returns 0.

Comment: I would add a check in that method to see whether the `recordings` array is nil.  If it is, check the error parameter in the executeFetch.

Comment: @pbasdf I'm checking the `recordings` array and it is NOT nil.

Comment: I just realized I might not be saving my files thoroughly.  Included the code I use to add data to core data.

Comment: Do you save the context anywhere?  You should have something like: `[context save:&error]` in order to ensure that updates are saved back to the database.

Answer (score 0):

I've been counting on auto-save to take care of the saving and it worked fine until I started forcing crashes to see how the app recovered.  Since the data was disappearing after every crash, I decided to try and save manually and it worked.  Now the data appears even after a forced crash.  I'm assuming this means auto-saving wasn't occurring in time.  Not exactly sure how to explain it, but saving the context manually resolved my issue.

```
[self.document saveToURL:self.document.fileURL forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForOverwriting completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
    if(success)
    {
        NSLog(@" NEW FILE SAVED");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"FAIL TO SAVE");
    }

}];
```

Comment: Autosave only occurs periodically, not automatically when changes are made.  So there is a period of time between you making a change, and it being autosaved.  If you crash during that period, your data will be lost.  Your manual save avoids this issue.